# Cython problem in Windows XP: "error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat"

Tags: python, mingw, cython

Cython version is 0.13, Python 3.1
I have tried all "solutions" in Cython FAQ, but to no avail. My version of Visual Studio is 7.1 and its directory doesn't contain vcvarsall.bat. Is this problem have a solution?

Comment: I guess you have Windows SDK 7.1 as there's no such thing as Visual Studio 7.1

Answer (score 2):

SO search and you will find ample discussion on this.

- https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=vcvarsall.bat

[Edit: based on comment below]

When you run setup.py install on windows, distutils looks for vcvarsall.bat to run.

**About vcvarsall.bat**

VCVarsall.bat is Visual Studio Command Prompt tool in Visual Studio. It allows you to set various options for the integrated development environment (IDE) as well as build, debug, and deploy projects from the command line.

**What if it does not find this file**

> Solution 1: Hunt the file

1. distutils has an hardcoded path to vcvarsall.bat.
2. find the file starting with vc*.bat or vc*.cmd. The file which sets up command line environment for MS compiler tool chain. The location is inconsistent for different versions of visual studio setup. If you are running 32 bit version then you should be able to find vcvars32.bat.
3. drop it in the directory distutils expect it to be.

Comment: Unfortunately MinGW-based solutions don't work too. As I can understand, VC2008 is needed. This is not an option for me.

Comment: Python 2,7 was built VC 2008, but OP says he has Visual Studio 7.1 which does not have a `vcvarsall.bat`. `distutils` is trying to to build extension using same compiler as Python itself. There's a way to override that but it didn't work for the extension I was trying to install. One possible solution, which I'm considering but haven't tried yet is to download and install the free [Visual Studio Express 2008 SP1](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=F3FBB04E-92C2-4701-B4BA-92E26E408569&displaylang=en) edition from Microsoft and trying again.

Comment: @martineau: Your extensions should be compiled with the same compiler as  the one with which python has been compiled. The issues are too many otherwise. Yup, it is a good idea to use the free version. Normally, you should find the vcvarsall.bat. MS has varied the approach far too often!

Comment: *distutils has an hardcoded path to vcvarsall.bat* For what this path actually is see [find_vcvarsall()](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/8527427914a2/Lib/distutils/msvc9compiler.py#l219) function in `msvc9compiler.py` module.