# Cython ->ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1915

Tags: python, python-3.x, mingw, cython

I have just installed Cython and minGW.After my first run this is what I got:

```
D:\Google drive\Python\Cython test>py setup.py build_ext --inplace
running build_ext
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 7, in <module>
    ext_modules = cythonize("helloworld.pyx")

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\core.py", line 148, in setup
    dist.run_commands()

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 966, in run_commands
    self.run_command(cmd)

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\dist.py", line 985, in run_command
    cmd_obj.run()

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\command\build_ext.py", line 308, in run
    force=self.force)

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\ccompiler.py", line 1031, in new_compiler
    return klass(None, dry_run, force)

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 282, in __init__
    CygwinCCompiler.__init__ (self, verbose, dry_run, force)

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.dll_libraries = get_msvcr()

  File "C:\Users\Laci\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\distutils\cygwinccompiler.py", line 86, in get_msvcr
    raise ValueError("Unknown MS Compiler version %s " % msc_ver)

ValueError: Unknown MS Compiler version 1915
```

I am using Win 10, Python 3.7, MinGW Date: 2017-09-06.
The MinGW/bin directory is already added to PATH.
distutils.cfg looks like this:

```
[build]
compiler = mingw32
```

Thank you for the help in advance!
L

Comment: I'm not sure minwg32 works with a current Python version which is built with a much latter version of MSVC. It is safer to use MSVC here. Or if you feel like experimenting, you could disable `raise ValueError` in distutils/cygwinccompiler.py` and see what happens.

Comment: what happens if you pass --compiler=mingw32 to setup.py?

Comment: @Silmathoron, I got the same error.

Comment: @ead, you could be right, I will test it soon. I tried minwg32 because it was suggested on the Cython website.

Comment: are you compiling in C or C++? you could also try to set CC or CXX to mingw, but using MSVC is usually the better choice on windows

Comment: @ead, I just tried to disable "Valuerror". Now I got a different message, but still not working.  http://prntscr.com/lnkl6f

Comment: I have no idea @Silmathoron. :-) I think Cython is compiling to C++, but not sure. I have deleted MinGW and Installed Visual studio 2017. Now I got the error: " Unable to find vcvarsall.bat".

Comment: this one's a [classic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4041677/5962321)

Comment: Problem solved. minwg didn't work, but I installed Build Tools for Visual Studio 2017, and it works well with Python 3.6.